# Running automated Tests in TFS manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I would like to run my automated tests separated from my build process. That means I ideally would like to start it from time to time by myself with the TFS Web interface.

This is not a unit but an integration test. So it takes some minutes an I want to keep it away from build process.

Everyting works fine when I use the test runner from build process, I also added some test to a Testplan, I tried to start it, but it does not work. I used the Microsoft Test Center but I list myself in configuring Testenvironments, added Buildplans, Testsetting, ...

Could anyone help?

best regards

Comment: Why not just run it from your desktop?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or does the test not run at all?